# Private VSTS docker agent not publishing to network share folder

Tags: docker, azure-devops

How can I publish my build artifacts to an ***network file share path***?
Using a private docker VSTS agent.

The Artifact publish location will look like this

```
\\releasetest\Artifacts\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

From what i have read online i have to use the  `-v` paramater.

```
 $ docker run -it --name <containername> -v \\releasetest\Artifacts\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber):/$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) <imagename>
```

***UPDATE***

> C:\Windows\system32>docker run -e
>   AZP_URL=https://dev.azure.com/companyname -e
>   AZP_TOKEN=token -e
>   AZP_AGENT_NAME=BuildFive -e AZP_POOL=PSBuildContainer -e
>   AZP_WORK=_work -v /releasetest/Artifacts/:/azp dockeragent:latest
>
> docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification:
>   '/releasetest/Artifacts/:/azp'. See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: Did you try with -v ? I also think this is a correct way which satisfied your demand. Does any error you encountered?

Comment: This is my exact call I am making ------
docker run -e AZP_URL=https://dev.azure.com/payspace -e AZP_TOKEN=Secrete -e AZP_AGENT_NAME=BuildOne -e AZP_POOL=PSBuildContainer -e AZP_WORK=_work -v \\releasetest\Artifacts:/c:azp dockeragent:latest
----- and the error is ----
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '\\releasetest\Artifacts:/c:azp'.

Comment: Sooo sorry for late response. This because linux could not parse the folder path of windows. Please try with `/releasetest/Artifacts/$(Build.DefinitionName)/$(Build.BuildNumber)`

Comment: No worries, just to clarify that my docker instance is running on an windows machine. Also i did try the above that also did not work. I updated the question to show exactly what i see. Seems like i am missing something silly